# MAUI App: Release output result is different from debug

Tags: c#, xaml, maui

I've a button that in **debug mode** looks like this (and is what i would like to have also in release mode):

```
           BUTTON DISABLED                              BUTTON ENABLED
```

[image: debug-empty]
[image: debug-filled]

In **release mode** tho, it looks like this:

```
           BUTTON DISABLED                              BUTTON ENABLED
```

[image: release-empy]
[image: release-filled]

See how the background color when the button is enabled in release mode, instead of being sort of a brown color, it's gray. I don't know why

```
<ContentView xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:viewmodels="clr-namespace:CurrencyExchange.ViewModels"
             x:Class="CurrencyExchange.CustomControls.FilterControl"
             xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:CurrencyExchange.Converters"
             xmlns:cstmctrls="clr-namespace:CurrencyExchange.CustomControls"
             x:Name="this">

    <ContentView.Resources>
        <converters:EnableSearchButtonConverter x:Key="EnableSearchButton"/>
    </ContentView.Resources>

    <Frame Padding="10, 0 ,0 ,0"
           Margin="10"
           WidthRequest="300" HeightRequest="60"
           CornerRadius="30">
        <Grid ColumnDefinitions="*, Auto, Auto">

            <Entry x:Name="filterLabel"
                   VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                   Placeholder="Insert the Location"
                   FontSize="18"
                   WidthRequest="200"
                   BindingContext="{x:Reference this}"
                   Text="{Binding Filter}"/>

            <Button Grid.Column="1"
                    Text="{StaticResource SearchIcon}" FontFamily="FAS" FontSize="20"
                    CornerRadius="50"
                    WidthRequest="50" HeightRequest="50"
                    Margin="6"
                    BindingContext="{x:Reference this}"
                    IsEnabled="{Binding Source={x:Reference filterLabel}, Path=Text, Converter={StaticResource EnableSearchButton}}"
                    Command="{Binding SearchCommand}"
                    Clicked="Button_Clicked">

            </Button>

        </Grid>
    </Frame>
</ContentView>
```

This was my custom control, with the entry and the button that should have a different background color, before i've noticed this problem. So i've added this code to try to solve the problem, without success.

```
<Button.Style>
   <Style TargetType="Button">
      <Style.Triggers>
         <Trigger TargetType="Button" Property="IsEnabled" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="{StaticResource Primary}"/>
         </Trigger>
         <Trigger TargetType="Button" Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="LightGray"/>
         </Trigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
   </Style>
</Button.Style>
```

Any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: please trim your images. Scrolling your question and seeing only white space is pretty annoying. Apart from this I can't see any difference between these images.

Comment: ye i noticed that. how do i do that? xD

Comment: manipulate the image on your machine with any image-tool you have before uploading it.

Comment: Ok, now should be clear enough

Answer (score 0):

After a deeeeep research, looks like it's a bug grr

[You can find details here](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/8961)

So, to work around that, my triggers were almost right, except for the properties used. Intead of background color, using just background looks like is fixing this issue.

```
<Button.Style>
   <Style TargetType="Button">
      <Style.Triggers>
         <Trigger TargetType="Button" Property="IsEnabled" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource Primary}"/>
         </Trigger>
         <Trigger TargetType="Button" Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#d3d3d3"/>
         </Trigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
   </Style>
</Button.Style>
```

**UPDATE**